# Can I refrigerate homemade puff pastry made ahead of time?

Tags: puff-pastry

Puff pastry is similar to croissant dough. When I made homemade croissants for the first time, a few weeks ago, they were OK but I could have done better. I have a recipe to use with puff pastry but I won't have a chance to redo the puff, if I make it from scratch and mess it up, or thaw store bought.

So if I make the dough ahead of time, can I refrigerate it for use the next morning? Ideally two days ahead but one day before morning use would be fine.

**EDIT:** Jacques Pepin, in his book "New Complete Techniques" says the following.

> Puff paste tends to darken and become quite elastic when stored in the
>   refrigerator. However, well wrapped, it freezes beautifully.
>
> The dough can be frozen whole or rolled, cut into shapes, and frozen.
>   To use, defrost the large pieces to roll. The frozen shaped pieces
>   should be placed in the oven frozen for best results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic puff pastry absolutely needs a final resting and cooling time in the fridge before you use it for your croissants, palmiers, danishes....

Most recipes give a *minimum* rest of 30-60 minutes after the last "fold", but overnight in the fridge is absolutely fine. I'm not sure whether storing it for two days might have negative side effects, but up to one day is no problem at all.